# How to find included .h files if you're using vim?

Tags: vim

If I have a few `#include`lines at the top, and I want to see the files that are included, in Eclipse one can control+click on the file name. Is there any equivalent for vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is a local included one, then you can type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> while having your cursor over the name of that file.

This is the command to do a "go file", so you leave the current file and jump to the selected file.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer may work for VIM, but in general, if these are header files that you are providing, you should look in the project directory to see them, as they should contain a path and then the file such as `#include "path/to/the/header.h"`
From here you simply navigate to the header file. For header files included with `<Angle Braces.h>` you'll need to look into your compiler specific folders

Comment: I just started working on a large project. The path is just `"example.h"` and it's not in the same file, nor is it in the path, but it compiles fine.

Comment: This tells me that the make file must be doing some of the work for you in determining where files are located. Check either in the makefile (literally just called `makefile`) or in `makefile.globals`. Are you using an IDE to compile this, or command line?

Comment: Yes, makefiles are being used to compile the project. I'm using command line. There are about 15 makefiles, making finding each header file a headache without an IDE.

Comment: How many files are in your project? Are there 15 separate projects that you are combining to make yours? 15 makefiles seems a little excessive, even for medium-large projects

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer shortly after posting.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor